# How to use `git describe` on repos without tags?

Tags: git

For most of our repos, we use `git describe --tags` to print a version number like `v1.0.4-14-g2414721`. However, this fails if the repo doesn't have any tags yet.

Is there a flag of `git describe` or something similar that would work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[git-describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) offers `--always` to give a fallback option. If you have any tags those are used, otherwise just the most recent commit id.